# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException - not sure what's going wrong

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I'm currently trying to write a scanner which take a dataset and parses it into an array. However I am experiencing the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at neural.neuralmain.readFile(neuralmain.java:34)
    at neural.neuralmain.<init>(neuralmain.java:97)
    at neural.neuralmain.main(neuralmain.java:201)
```

I have seen a number of topics on this topic here, and most seem to be to do with checking for there actually being a next item available for the scanner. I was under the impression my code did this, so some help would be appreciated.

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
public int[][] readFile( int[][] inputArray, String filename, int dataType) {

    // A "try" block is used, as the constructor will throw an Exception should the filename not be recognised.
    try {
        // The code reads from the scanner, in, which is attached to the filename.
        Scanner input = new Scanner( new File( filename ) );

        //Initialising the array to store the input data.
        inputArray = new int[dataType][65];

        //  The data files are arranged into characters, with the first 64 values corresponding to one 4x4 area and
        //  the 65th corresponds to the character class. This combination loops writes the input file as an array.
        //  The class is the zeroth element and 1st-64th elements are the divided pixel areas.
        for ( int i = 0; i <= dataType; i++ ){
            for ( int j = 1; j <= 65; j++ ){
                while( !input.hasNextInt() ){
                    input.next();
                }
                inputArray[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
            while( !input.hasNextInt() ){
                input.next();
            }
            inputArray[i][0] = input.nextInt();
        }


        // When the program exits from the two previous "for" loops the program has finished reading from
        // the scanner, "input", and the scanner is closed.
        input.close();
        System.out.println("File successfully read in.");

        return inputArray;
    }
    catch (IOException error){

        // If the "try" block fails due to a file not being found, then an exception will be thrown.  
        System.out.println("File name not recognised. A blank array has been produced.");

        // An array of zeroes is created
        inputArray = new int[dataType][65];

        return inputArray;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

(If it helps I'm using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2))

Comment: What is line 34 in `neuralmain.java`? How does your read file looks like?

Comment: Is your class named `neuralmain`? Which ones are the lines 34, 97 and 201?

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this is not a code dump, but a simple (and short) but still runnable code which we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you. This will lead to less confusion and more, faster and better responses :)

Comment: *"most seem to be to do with checking for there actually being a next item available for the scanner. I was under the impression my code did this"* Not really. You're just checking `!input.hasNextInt()` which is true if the next token is not an `int` _and_ if there are no more tokens and what will happen if there are no more tokens and you call `input.next();`?